# On a ButtonClick how to load ViewFlipper's second child

Tags: android, viewflipper

I have four child Layout in My ViewFlipper. By default the view Flipper loads its first child but I want to load the second child of the ViewFlipper on a button press or setting **onClickListener** on a button.

I used these two methods also **setDisplayedChild()** and **indexOfChild()** but its not working for me.

```
 vF.setDisplayedChild(vF.indexOfChild(findViewById(R.id.view)));
```

*I went through a lot of question related to viewFlipper but I am not able to find the solution what I am looking for.*

Comment: Have you tried `showNext()` and `showPrevious()`?

Comment: Can you check what value is returned with `vF.indexOfChild(findViewById(R.id.view))`?

Comment: ya i have tried but its not working @Skizo

Comment: Do you have any error or something in LogCat? Can you post the ViewFlipper xml and your includes on it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try instead of `vF.setDisplayedChild(vF.indexOfChild(findViewById(R.id.view)));` use the methods that `ViewFlipper` owns [`showNext()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewAnimator.html#showNext()) and [`showPrevious()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewAnimator.html#showPrevious()), it should work for you, but also the first code that you provided, so make sure that your `findViewById()` is correct and see what returns.

For more info see this [tutorial](http://www.inter-fuser.com/2009/07/android-transistions-slide-in-and-slide.html)

Comment: @Gauravsingh Can you post the xml please?

Comment: @Gauravsingh Solved your problem?

Comment: sorry for the late reply,yes the problem was solved.thanku

Comment: you can mark this answer as a correct if it helped you ;)